# Create several bean with constructer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create several beans with constructer but it keeps failing.

> ServerStater.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerStarter.class, args);

        NettyTcpServer server1 = context.getBean(NettyTcpServer.class, (Integer) 10001);
        server1.start();

        NettyTcpServer server2 = context.getBean(NettyTcpServer.class, (Integer) 10002);
        server2.start();
    }
}
```

> NettyTcpServer

```
@Component
public class NettyTcpServer {

    private int port;

    @Autowired
    public NettyTcpServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

   ...
}
```

So, basically, I want to make two beans which have different variable values with the same class. I made Constructer which will get a port to open TCP socket, and I passed the int parameter when creating the beans when the program is started. Do I miss understood how to use these annotations? I atteched error message when running.

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.telcuon.korail.netty.NettyTcpServer
>   required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration.
>   [WARNING]  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'nettyTcpServer' defined in file
>   [C:\Java\TCO-AppCard-Korail-Branch-Server\target\classes\com\telcuon\korail\netty\NettyTcpServer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'int' available: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>     at com.telcuon.korail.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:22)     ...
>   6 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'int' available: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758)
>     ... 24 more

Comment: So what's the problem with this code?

Comment: How is it failing? Are you getting error messages? We can't help you without knowing the problem.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've just added error messages.

Comment: Try removing @Autowired from the constructor in NettyTcpServer.